# Getting 'Invalid URL' in paypal response

Tags: paypal, salesforce, integration, response

I've integrated paypal(sandbox) in salesforce; which was working fine couple of days back. Now I'm receiving the following in my response :

> Invalid URL
>
> ## Invalid
>   URL
>
> The requested URL "/2.0/", is invalid.< p>
>   Reference #9.1be0fc7d.1380276647.e8c0af1

Also I'm getting the exception as follows

> System.XmlException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,3]
>       Message: The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "< /p>".

could anyone let me know how to over come this issue.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
Uzair

Answer (score 0):

the HTML page was returned you by Paypal, most probably there is an error details there. try to read the content of HTML to understand the reason of error.
There are a lot of reasons why it could be failed.